# Laravel Collection whenNotEmpty and whenEmpty in same chain

Tags: laravel

I want to return null when the result is empty and return array when its not empty so i used `whenNotEmpty`, `whenEmpty` in the same chain:

```php
collect($items)->map(/**some operation*/)
    ->whenEmpty(fn() => null)
    ->whenNotEmpty(fn($collection) => $collection->toArray());
```

I'll get one of these errors (in different order)

> Error : Call to a member function whenNotEmpty() on null

or

> Error : Call to a member function whenEmpty() on array

So how can i use these methods in one chain ?

Comment: `->whenEmpty(fn() => null)` is the problem. it should return the collection to maintain the chain. now collection is null and cannot call `whenNotEmpty`. [DOC](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-whenempty)

Comment: `->whenNotEmpty(fn($collection) => $collection->toArray())` this returning array not collection. it should return the collection to maintain the chain. check the documentation link

Comment: Ok i asked is there anyway to achieve that ?

Comment: try the second parameter of the `->whenEmpty()` method

Comment: @ml59 thanks, It worked: `whenEmpty(fn() => null, fn($collection) => $collection->toArray());` feel free to send your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment, try the second parameter of the `->whenEmpty()` method.
Here is the definition `public function whenEmpty(callable $callback, callable $default = null)` 
Cordially